# Custom control defined in an assembly with ControlTemplates defined in another

Tags: wpf, styles, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have created a library with custom controls to simplify some developments of my coworkers.
I then have created a template in which I would like to give them the opportunity to modify default templates and so on.
After some researches, I found some information on Themes, Generic.xaml and ThemeInfo attribute but something doesn't work.

So my last attempt:
- The control library with Theme attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //où se trouvent les dictionnaires de ressources spécifiques à un thème
//(utilisé si une ressource est introuvable dans la page, 
// ou dictionnaires de ressources de l'application)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.ExternalAssembly //où se trouve le dictionnaire de ressources générique
//(utilisé si une ressource est introuvable dans la page, 
// dans l'application ou dans l'un des dictionnaires de ressources spécifiques à un thème)
```

)]

All controls inherit from System.Windows.Control and have a static constructor with:

```
DefaultStyleKeyProperty.
         OverrideMetadata(typeof(Tire), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Tire)));
```

Then, in the application, where this library is referenced, I have a Themes/Generic.xaml file with such definitions:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type g:Tire}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type g:Tire}">
                <Viewbox Name="view">
                    <Ellipse Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="10" Width="30" 
                             Height="30"/>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Present}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="view" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Present}" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="view" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also tried setting a key with `{x:Type g:Tire}`ou simplement `g:Tire` but without success: the controls are rendered without control templates in VS2010.

To successfully display the controls, I have to add the generic.xaml file as a ResourceDictionary in app.xaml, whereas I add the ThemeInfo attribute or not in this second assembly.

An other related issue: if in a window.xaml file or another control xaml file, to use the power of styles, I add:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type g:Tire}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
</Style>
```

the system seems to override the style defined in generic.xaml and the control template is not rendered anymore. To check I looked at the Template property in the property grid and the origin of the value is referenced as "Defined in Style" instead of the classic "Inheritance" when a custom control is defined in the same assembly.

So my question, could someone point me where I should look to overcome this situation or help me find the right way to prepare such a setup : define controls in a Class library, and, using the default style mechanism, define the control templates in a generic.xaml file in a wpf application ?

Thanks in advance !

**Update:**

I've looked upon a few things and it is a bit more clear: as I don't intend to use theming in the general way, I have to set in some way the style system to use a resourcedictionnary defined in the customer library as the "generic" dictionary.

By adding ThemeInfo(...None, ...None) in the source assembly and addind the customer xaml file as resource in the customer assembly, I managed to change the value returned by `DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(customControl1, Library.CustomControl.TemplateProperty).BaseValueSource` from `Style` to `Default`, but Template is still overwritten if a style is defined in the application:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Library;assembly=Library">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="my:CustomControl"></Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <my:CustomControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="128,95,0,0" Name="customControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="157" Width="253" />
</Grid>
```

Moreover, in the property grid, the source of the Template property is still set as Style...

I guess I am now looking at a way to set the style as implicit or default or something.. (the one defined in the customer assembly for a control defined in the source assembly).

Comment: To be clear, I am now using a simple CustomControl defined in a Library class library, in a WpfApp customer application to simplify explanations and find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me which part is not working and what template you want to give to your coworkers to modify the default appearance, but that's what you need to do with Custom Controls in WPF:

Create a custom control class inherited from

```
System.Windows.Controls.Control
```

You got the constructor part correctly, so the next step is to create a folder in the same project as your custom control with the name 'Themes' and add Generic.xaml in there. That's where the WPF will look for the default control template.

Define a style which implements your target type:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Tire}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Tire}">
                <!--  there goes your template: grids / stackpanels, etc -->
```

For each project where you want to use the control you have a chance to redefine the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type custom:Tire}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
    <!-- any customer dependency property can be set here as well-->
```

If you want those properties to actually change you need to use TemplatedParent in your source assembly to bind those properties rather than hard-coding them.

Comment: Thanks for the support, but what I am looking here is to define this default style in the customer assembly with an implicit maneer. This way, if one wants to define an explicit style in the same application (so not the assembly in which the controls are actually defined), it can do so without adding a "basedon" directive and keep the Template defined (not in the source assembly).

Comment: Right, as long as you have the style defined in the source assembly in generic.xaml it'll apply to customer assembly. If a customer want to override the default style they can always do so. The last xaml example shows just that.

Comment: Yes but what if I don't want any style defined in the source assembly, have one defined as default style in an implicit way in the customer assembly so that we can add an explicit in the same assembly whitout overriding all the style (for exemple to set a margin, or a size..) ?

Comment: From my experience, whenever you create a style it will only override those properties which you specifically want to override. At this point there is no difference where you have a style in a source assembly or client assembly (what you mention implicit style). its the same effect, except that from WPF standpoint you have to have a style in your source assembly in generic.xaml. I suggest you to try it out and you'll see it yourself.

Comment: I have already tried in fact :). In the update of my question, you can see in the Grid resources an empty style, so it shouldn't override anything. The style containing the ControlTemplate is defined in a xaml file added as a ResourceDictionary in app.xaml.  Unfortunately, if I let empty style, my control disappear (unless I add the basedon property, which I do not want to)... I will put some source online to better explain.